# Connecting to a remote web server and SQL database using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, hosting

I need to set up asp.net and SQL server database hosting with a 3rd party web hosting service. To simplify the deployment process, I'd like to be able to develop the web site within a Visual Studio environment in exactly the same way as VS allows local machine or domain web sites to be edited.
I'd also like to be able to connect to the 3rd party SQL database directly - possibly using SQL server linked servers, or asp.net connection objects.

Is it possible to do this? What services do 3rd party hosts need to provide in order to allow integration with Visual Studio and SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good windows hosting company will by default offer you publishing using Web Deploy method and Web Matrix.Their web servers are designed to handle direct connectivity with Visual Studio and SQL Database Server.

I am using [AccuWebHosting](http://www.accuwebhosting.com/) services and they're offering seamless connectivity using [**Web Deploy**](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/798/How-to-deploy-Visual-Studio-2010-Web-Application-Project-using-Web-Deploy-method.html) and [**Web Matrix**](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/816/How-to-deploy-WebMatrix-Beta-Web-Application-Project-using-Web-Deploy.html).

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect with the other machine that have the sql server, the server must left opened two posts, the 1433, and 1434.

With this port you can connect remotely.

But this is also left them open to all the other and maybe the attack begin, so you have two chooses here, ether to change the default port, ether use one SSH tunneling connection. With the tunneling connection the server run a tunneling server, you connect using a tunneling client, and you map this ports to the tunneling both on client and on server, and then you connect to the server via secure connection and with out open the sql ports. I hope that all this make sense.

Comment: So I need a web host that allows users to connect via the SQL Server ports, or one that supports SSH tunneling connections?

Comment: @Trent better is the support of the tunneling.